# Is their a grid_remember()? Reversible grid_forget()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am confused on the documentation surrounding the tkinter "grid_forget()"
I know that this function does not **permanently** delete the widget ascribed to it, however I do not know how to call it again. Further, if the widget is forgotten in a frame, can it be called back to the same the frame?

Comment: Whats the confusion. How do you place a widget in the first place? Maybe you should try to do that after you use forget().

Answer (score 12):

You can call `grid()` with no parameters to reverse the effects of `grid_remove()`.

In the following example there is a label that is placed at the top of the window with `grid`. There is a toggle button that will alternate between calling `grid` and `grid_remove` to show that calling `grid` with no parameters will restore the message exactly as it was.

Notice, for example, that both the `row`, `column`, and `columnspan` attributes are remembered when the message reappears.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.toggle = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="Toggle the message",
                                command=self.toggle_message)
        self.toggle.pack(side="left")

        # simulate a typical app with a navigation area on the left and a main
        # working area on the right
        self.navpanel = tk.Frame(self.root, background="bisque", width=100, height=200)
        self.main = tk.Frame(self.root, background="white", width=300, height=200, bd=1, relief='sunken')
        self.message = tk.Label(self.root, text="Hello, world!")

        self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.message.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.navpanel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.main.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def toggle_message(self):
        if self.message.winfo_viewable():
            self.message.grid_remove()
        else:
            self.message.grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().start()
```

If you change the code from using `grid_remove` to using `grid_forget`, restoring the label will not put it back in the same place or with the same options. That is the main distinction between `grid_remove` and `grid_forget` -- `grid_forget` literally forgets the grid options whereas `grid_remove` removes the widget but remembers the settings.

Comment: This is helpful after clicking a button on your button frame to call a child process. The child process can hide all buttons with `.grid_remove()` when starting up and `.grid()` when finished to restore buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to illustrate what is happening when you remove a widget from the grid then re-grid it. You simply need to re apply the grid the same way you would have done in the first place. You can even chose a different grid location if you like. Though I am not sure if you can change the container it was originally assigned to. If not then it will only be able to be re-added to the original container the widget was assigned to.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

some_label = tk.Label(root, text="IM HERE!")
some_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

def forget_label():
    some_label.grid_forget()

def return_label():
    some_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

tk.Button(root, text="Forget Label", command=forget_label).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="Return Label", command=return_label).grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```